# my TabPage is not maximizing simultaneously with the windows form

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am designing a tabbed webbrowser with VB 2010. When runing the application, if I maximizes the window the TabControl doesn't maximize (it's size stays fixed). Please how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly. 
Make your tab control's Anchor property = Top|Left|Bottom|Right